# Pyplot table : cellColours only works if square array

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, colors, cell

I want to colour cells of a non-square table and have the following code :

```
meg = [[1, 2], [3, 2], [5, 0]]

df = DataFrame(meg, columns=[str(i) for i in range(len(meg[0]))])
vals = df.values
normal = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.amin(meg),vmax=np.amax(meg))
the_table = plt.table(colLabels=df.columns, colWidths=[0.1]*vals.shape[1], loc='center', cellColours=plt.cm.hot_r(normal(vals)))
plt.show()
```

This code works if the array is a square array but not if it's not and I can't figure out why.

The error I get when I try to launch the program with the 3x2 array is :

> ValueError: 'cellColours' must have 2 rows

Comment: The code you show here runs fine for me on matplotlib version 2.0.2. It produces [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNnpy.png).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I obtain the same result after updating matplotlib. However, I'm now trying to display a bigger table with the following code :

```
meg = randn(80, 38)

df = DataFrame(meg, columns=[str(i) for i in range(len(meg[0]))])
vals = df.values
normal = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.amin(meg), vmax=np.amax(meg))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=True, xticks=[], yticks=[])
the_table=plt.table(colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', cellColours=plt.cm.hot(normal(vals)))
plt.show()
```

but I don't know if it's possible to adapt the height of the table to the window ?